# Questions with Regard to Organizing Checkbox (Multiple Answers) Choices into Two Columns

Tags: database, database-design, redcap

In my REDCap project, I have a checkboxes (multiple answers) field with numerous choices. The list of choices is rather long, and I was wondering if it were possible to break down the list of choices into two separate columns, so that the viewing experience will be more pleasant for the survey respondent. Any input regarding this would be much appreciated. Thanks so much!

EDIT: I had not thoroughly researched this topic prior to asking this question, and for that I thoroughly apologize. As I mentioned below,
There is a @COLUMNS action tag in REDCap available that allows you to separate your choices into columns. The syntax for the @COLUMNS action tag is as follows:

@COLUMNS=# of columns

e.g. @COLUMNS=5 would separate the choices into five separate columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a @COLUMNS action tag in REDCap available that allows you to separate your choices into columns. The syntax for the @COLUMNS action tag is as follows:

@COLUMNS=# of columns

e.g. @COLUMNS=5 would separate the choices into five separate columns.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the checkbox question into two separate questions and use field embedding to have them shown side by side.

People often use tables, but Bootstrap grids work better because they're responsive, so you could have two columns for monitors, say, and one for mobile devices. Something like this:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">{cb1}</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">{cb2}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(Nb. remove the line breaks from the HTML above in the Online Designer)